# Returning nested divs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return a structure similar to this

```
<div style="someCSS">
  <div style="someOtherCSS"></div>
  <div style="someOtherCSS"></div>
</div>
<div style="someCSS">
  <div style="someOtherCSS"></div>
  <div style="someOtherCSS"></div>
  <div style="someOtherCSS"></div>
</div>
```

I am working around this idea, but it's not quite right, and I don't know what to do.

```
const nestedDivs = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
         let someOtherCSS{
          borderColor: '#fff',
          borderSize: '1px',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          background: '#ffcc00',
         };
      fooStyle.push(<div style={someOtherCSS}></div>);
      }
       let someCSS{
          borderColor: '#fff',
          borderSize: '1px',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          background: '#ff0000',
         };
      fooStyle.unshift(<div style={someCSS}></div>);
    }
    return fooStyle;
}
```

Comment: push/shift won't create nested anything - they'll create a flat array - also `let someOtherCSS{ .... }` doesn't look like valid code at all, unless that is some `reactjs` majicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is executing properly and just have issue with appending *someOtherCSS* divs into *someCSS*, then you can try this,

```
const nestedDivs = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        const innerDives = [];
        for (let j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
            let someOtherCSS{
                borderColor: '#fff',
                borderSize: '1px',
                borderStyle: 'solid',
                background: '#ffcc00',
            }
            innerDives.push(<div style={someOtherCSS}></div>);
        }
        let someCSS{
            borderColor: '#fff',
            borderSize: '1px',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            background: '#ff0000',
        }
        fooStyle.push(<div style={someCSS}>{innerDives}</div>);
    }
    return fooStyle;
}
```

**Hope this will helpful to you! Happy coding...**

Comment: This is it! 
The snippet I posted is a very simplified version of the actual code I was working on.
Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a below try also, it uses text for concat the html and then dangerouslySetInnerHTML to string HTML.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let someHtml = ``;
  let x = 5;
  let y = 10;
  for (let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    someHtml += `<div className='someCSS'>`
    for (let j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
      someHtml += `<div className='someOtherCSS'></div>`;
    }
    someHtml += '</div>'
  }


  return (
    <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: someHtml}} />
  );
}

export default App;
```